# Deleting rows in multiple dataframes

Tags: r

I have a large number of DFs. I would like to apply a change to all the DFs, but can't figure it out.

I would like to delete rows where the Class = Poor, and keep all others.

```
 DF1:
 Name  Class Weight Jan_income Feb_income
 John  Rich   92     10000      45454
 Sam   Poor   23     100        4552
 Laura Poor   45     123        7542


 DF2:
 Name  Class Weight Jan_income Feb_income
 Mark  Poor     23     1031       5434
 Sam   Middle   23     100        951
 Laura Poor     45     123        421
```

I can do this for one DF

```
 DF1 <- DF1 [!(DF1$Class == "Poor"),]
```

I am happy to keep the existing DF names. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would put all `data.frame`s in a `list`; then operate on them with `lapply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to place it in a `list`.  If the names have a `pattern`, then use `mget` with `ls`

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^DF\\d+$")), subset,  Class != "Poor")
```

If the datasets have the same column names, then

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lst1)
```

Or use the same code as the OP, with anonymous function call

```
lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^DF\\d+$")), function(x) x[[!(x$Class == "Poor"),])
```

---

Or another option is `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
out1 <- map_dfr(mget(ls(pattern = "^DF\\d+$")), ~ .x %>%
                                          filter(Class != "Poor"))
```

---

If the intention is to have a single data.frame, it would be better not to create multiple objects in the global environment i.e. if we read the datasets from files, read it to a `list` directly and subset the rows

```
library(readr)
map_dfr(files, read_csv, .id = 'grp') %>%
       filter(Class != "Poor")
```

Or in `base R`

```
out2 <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, grp = seq_along(files), lapply(files, read.csv)))
subset(out2, Class != "Poor")
```

Comment: this is very helpful. How do I get the output into a df? The results are only being displayed in the console. Sorry for such a basic question.